# Problems logging into "quay.io" (docker)

Tags: docker

While not in any container, I try `docker login quay.io`.

When not as `root` I get:  `Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.Secret.Error.IsLocked: Cannot create an item in a locked collection
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: Cannot create an item in a locked collection`

When `root` *(not running in an X11 session because I shouldn't have to?)* I get:  `Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`

Looking right now for an online *"real* howto" for setting up Docker in Ubuntu and installing something that's stored on Quay.  (Quay's documents, such as they are, merely assume that you know what you're doing already.)

Comment: It sounds as if you've been running `docker` with something like `sudo`. Try fixing the permissions on your `~/.docker` directory and re-running `docker login quay.io` as your non-root user.

Comment: Nope ... even with `sudo` and even as a member of the `docker` group, the command does not succeed without an X11 environment.  It apparently wants to store the credentials in a "keyring" that only exists in such an environment.  Raised as issue `https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2229` ...

Comment: I think you misread my comment. I was suggesting that you first fix the ownership on `~/.docker`, and then run the command *without* sudo.